# What is the difference between browser based VPN and desktop VPN by anonymity point of view?

Tags: vpn, proxy, anonymity

For example : 
Nordvpn provides both chrome extension and its desktop software.
Opera provides a free browser vpn, etc..

Some people says the browser extensions may leak dns but i never had an experience with it (by dns leak tests).

What about them on http:// (non https) sites? Is the ISP can see what websites we visit even with browser vpn extension (a paid vpn with no dns leaks) enabled?

Answer (score 2):

A browser based VPN is not actually a virtual private **network** but instead an encrypted tunnel to a proxy server. Since it is integrated in the browser it is unlikely to cause DNS leaks. All DNS will instead be resolved by the proxy at the end of the encrypted tunnel. Such a browser based "VPN" will only cover traffic originating in the browser.

What you call a desktop VPN is a system wide VPN which covers every traffic targeted to the internet and originating on the local system, i.e. not only browser traffic. It will not cover traffic within the local network though. This might cause DNS leaks if the VPN fails to change the local DNS servers since the default DNS server in typical SoHo setupts is commonly the router.